# Encountered non-numerical values at (ParameticNDSolve/NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have the following problem: Even though I defined every other constant in the code, using either [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) or [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html), I get the error

> ParametricNDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r$13269 == 2.220446049250313`*^-16."

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the Code:

```
UPotential[χ_] := (m^2/(Subscript[m, f]^2*16))*χ^4*(4*Log[χ] - 1)
DUPotential[χ_] := D[UPotential[χ], χ]
m := 10^(-6)
Subscript[m, f] := 100 
EQ1 := D[u[r], r] + σ[r]*v[r] + ϵ*v[r]
EQ2 := D[v[r], r] + (2*v[r])/r + σ[r]*u[r] - ϵ*u[r]
EQ3 := -D[σ[r], {r, 2}] - (2/r)*D[σ[r], r] + DUPotential[σ[r]] + (u[r]^2 - v[r]^2)/(4*Pi)
sol = Block[
     {s = $MachineEpsilon}, 
     ParametricNDSolve[
      { 
        EQ1 == 0, 
        EQ2 == 0, 
        EQ3 == 0, 
        Derivative[1][σ][s] == 0, 
        σ[10] == 1, 
        u[10] == 0, 
        v[s] == 0
      }
     , {σ[r], v[r], u[r]}
     , {r, s, 10}
     , {ϵ}
    ]
]
σ[r][0] /. sol
```

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always show your due diligence and give brief context. Thanks for your example of your code in properly[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.